# Accidentally deleted all kernel versions

Tags: boot, kernel

I had dual booted my system with Windows 10 and Linux-Ubuntu-16.04.

I recently was modifying some configuration files in Linux-Kernel 4.17 which did not work so I had to delete that and restore to my normal 4.13 version. But in the verge of deleting I might have deleted both the kernels and now when I boot my system I can get only windows turned on with no option to select ubuntu.

Is it that my ubuntu has completely removed and I need to reinstall it again?

If I reinstall will I loose my present data in Windows and will I be able to gain data I stored in Linux OS?

What steps needs to be followed? Please help me out! I'm a core Linux user with all the files saved in it!

Comment: how did you delete kernels? via terminal or GUI? if you know the location, you may borrow the same files from other 16.04 running system and paste them in those locations via live session.

Comment: Can you please add to your question if you're using uefi or bios boot?

Comment: I could restore the files! I did delete those via terminal and used uefi boot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can reinstall your Ubuntu without hitting Windows at all
- To recover your data, I suggest you to use a bootable USB drive + another USB storage to save all important data inside it

---

To do this important step, you need to :

Boot on the USB, choose "Try Ubuntu" option (Live Ubuntu session)

Open a terminal, and type the following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l    ###find the partition which contains your data

sudo mount /dev/sdaN /mnt  ####N is the partition number (can be sdbN, sdcN too)
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo mount --bind /run  /mnt/run
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo chroot /mnt           ####after this command, you re inside your previous Ubuntu partition
```

Plug your storage USB, and mount it with :

```
sudo mount /dev/sdU /opt    ####where U is the USB partition, seen with fdisk -l
```

*NB: You can also mount your USB storage at another place than /opt, but I think it's the least restrictive*

---

Now, you can copy all data from your sick partition to your USB storage; just don't forget to unmount and unplugged this device with `sudo umount /opt` before starting the installation

You can now launch the re-installation of Ubuntu, just select the option "Remove Ubuntu" and not "Format the whole disk", you know what I mean

Comment: I would use `sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash`