# Ubuntu treats correct login as incorrect; also can't open terminal

Tags: login

I have this very old machine running Ubuntu 18.04, and out of the blue, it has stopped accepting my password, treating it as incorrect (not the login loop thing).

I searched here for possible fixes and was going to try them, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (or any <kbd>Fn</kbd> key for that matter) failed to bring up the terminal, they just did nothing.

Now I am at a loss, also because I really don't know the first thing about Ubuntu. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you really want to access terminal when **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **Fn** key didn't work, you can try recovery mode

Comment: I just tried, and...well, the default keyboard on my machine is apparently Cyrillic, so I can't type any commands when in terminal there.

Comment: So, I am thinking that the best way to solve this would be to boot from live USB and somehow make the system bypass the login step altogether. Can someone point me to how to do that?

Comment: you can use these [steps from one of my previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054554/accidentally-deleted-all-kernel-versions/1054560#1054560) on a live USB session to try to modify configuration file

Comment: I will try to, but my drive is encrypted (I really didn't make it easy for myself), so I will have to jump through some extra hoops. Thanks, this way I will at least be able to get a couple of files I need. Can I also enable automatic logic from liveusb somehow?

Comment: That was "automatic login", ofc